# Fill in data to textarea, when clicking on button and loading new page

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, forms, textarea

I am wondering if there is any possible way to fill in a form's textarea, by clicking on a button, which is on another page. The case is:

You visit Site A, which contains a button for extra information. This button links to a form, on another page. On button click the new page will be loaded and a value should be inside the textarea.

I am using Wordpress and for the form is created with NinjaTables.

Hopefully there are some helpful answers.

Comment: why cant you try session? and what data you need to fill in textarea

Comment: You can store the info in local storage before redirect, after redirect to the other page, fetch it from local storage, fill the textarea with it, delete it from local storage if needed

Comment: Sounds good, then I will need to look up how all this works. And charan kumur: I just wanna pass a string, nothing special